# concurrent http request limit

Tags: java, servlets, jetty

We're working dynamics offer system and have to make concurrent min. 6 http requests per visitor. I have coded connection manager with using this [example](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/examples/MultiThreadedExample.java?view=markup) for connecting different web-sites.
There are 3 different connection like;

```
www.x.com / 1000 ms 
www.y.com / 400 ms
www.z.com / 100 ms
```

I have to finish our request with in 1000ms and have 32 core and 64gb-ram for this job.

When our code tried to make http request with 120 users/sec, jetty says `INFO: I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection timed out` and our response time is increasing to 10 sec. per user.

I have some question for concurrent http request;

- I have changed my tcp and limit conf values like
  (tcp_time_wait_interval,tcp_keepalive_intvl, max-file-open,
  tcp_keepalive_intvl    etc.)  and is there any ethernet limit for
  concurrent request  ?
- Do you know good example for concurrent http request ?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are talking about browser.
Browsers have limit for making concurrent http requests. Modern browsers allow upto 8 concurrent http requests.

To avoid this, open a websocket between client and server and send your data using low level protocols like STOMP. This will avoid unnecessary headers and cookies being excahgned over network and is pretty fast.

Comment: I'm using loader.io for testing our application. Also, Our request has only get parameter. Thanks for your comment.